# Hierarchical UITableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview, ios4

In my first view I have a `UITableView` with 5 records. In `UITableView` cells are holding two different components. One `UILabel` is text and another `UILabel` shows value for that cell.

On selection of this `UITableViewCell` user is navigated to another view where I have given a picker controller for changing the value of 2nd label in the table view for the selected row. I reload the `UITableView` data on `-viewWillAppear` but this overlaps the text on lables as many times I visit it.

Can anyone give me relevant example of hierarchical tableview where `UItableViewCell`'s right section is dependant on selection of picker from next view.

Comment: I used this in cellForRowAtIndexPath. I add these dynamic lablels in the UITableViewcell.
 
 CGRect lblFrame = CGRectMake(10, 5, 140, 30);
 UILabel *lblField =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:lblFrame];
 lblField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:[UIFont labelFontSize]];  
 
 CGRect firstInput_Frame =CGRectMake(300, 5, 200, 30);
 UILabel *lblResult = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:firstInput_Frame];
 lblResult.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:[UIFont labelFontSize]];
 //[txtField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
 lblField.text=@"    ";
 lblResult.text = @"    "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are adding the labels on cell.contentView everytime you reload the table, but are not removing the previous ones. Thats why the overlapping is happening.

try to remove the lables

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    for (UIView * view in cell.contentView.subviews) {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
        view = nil;
    }
    // add your labels
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I would like to know if there is any other optimal solution for this. Will you like me to give more explanation of my problem.

Comment: May be some big shots from this portal might give us some optimal solution. As far as I know, we are not creating new cells everytime, but are dequeing reusable cells, which are already created and are having some views added to it, so before using such cell, i prefer cleaning the cell's view and then customize it. And when i do so, i release the added component..eg. [cell.contentView addSubView:myLabel]; [myLabel release]; so that there are no leaks.